# macOS partition missing, Internet Recovery not working

Tags: bootcamp, recovery

I installed Windows 10 through Bootcamp and it worked well, but with a persistent issue. Every time I restarted to macOS from Windows, the login screen would freeze up and I would have to do an additional restart every time. 2 days ago, the computer suddenly stopped mid-restart and flashed the apple logo every few seconds for about 10 minutes.

At this point I decided to try using Recovery Mode (⌘+R) but that redirected me to Internet Recovery, leading me to believe my macOS partition was gone. (I confirmed this later by looking at the disk in Windows, macOS is missing and only Bootcamp is left.)

Basically what happens when I try to use Recovery is it takes me to the spinning globe, where I enter my Wi-Fi password. Then it fills up the progress bar, but once it reaches 100% the screen goes black for a second and then it goes back to the "select a network" screen with the spinning globe. If I try to do it again it just loops.

If recovery won't work how am I supposed to repair/reinstall macOS? I just want to get to disk utility but it won't let me. Is there any other way? What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated as this is rather an urgent issue.

Comment: That's a tough one. Do a search for NVRAM/PRAM reset and SMC reset. Try both. Do you have another Mac to make an OS installer flash drive? Or a friend with a Mac? It *could* be a software error and if you can boot from a flash drive that might get you out of it.

Comment: Try using Recovery if you have access to an ethernet port (wired) on a router. I've found that sometimes WiFi just won't work well when doing an OTA macOS install. You don't specify if this is a laptop or desktop, and of what vintage, so you may need to purchase an ethernet to <whatever> adapter. Usually, a true USB3 or USBC adapter works well.

Comment: @SteveChambers Do either PRAM reset or SMC reset mess up Bootcamp? Windows is really the only way I can use my computer at the moment and I'd like to hang onto it in case macOS fixing doesn't work out. And unfortunately I do not have an ethernet cable.

Comment: If you boot your Mac Alt key pushed, what append?

Comment: nmokey: After installing the Boot Camp Support Software, did you run the Apple Software Update application installed to Windows 10? Often with older Macs there will be a update to a newer version of Boot Camp. This may avoid the restart to macOS problem you are describing.

Comment: PRAM/NVRAM and SMC reset do not effect BootCamp installations.

Comment: Update: I tried the NVRAM reset and let go after the second chime, and now the mac is stuck looping the chime over and over. I now cannot even boot into Windows. After shutting down and restarting, it just continues chiming. I created a bootable macOS installer but can’t use it because the computer doesn’t do anything but chime. Help?

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I just ran Apple Support Update application to check, and it told me my software was up-to-date.

Comment: @Jean_JD It lets me select from Bootcamp (which is what I am using to type this) and Macintosh HD. (I always do this to switch between the partitions.) But when I select and boot to macOS it just has the issue I described in the post.

Comment: You can retry a Reset SMC and  Reset NVRAM and let push the key during 1 minute (4 or 5 chime sound).